# Как из базы данных MS SQL прочитать тип image?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Здравствуйте! Вот два правильных варианта.**

****---1 вариант---**

**Default.aspx****

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
   <% Fun(); %>
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//подключить пространство имен
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication1 {
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
  public void Fun() {

   byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];

   string stringConnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["zzz"].ConnectionString;
   using(SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(stringConnect)) {
    connect.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT Photo FROM zzz";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connect);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read()) {
     byteArray = new byte[((byte[])reader["Photo"]).Length];
     byteArray = (byte[])reader["Photo"];

     /*обязательно нужно КОНВЕРТИРОВАТЬ подробнее здесь*/
     //https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
     string base64String;
     base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

     /*вот теперь здесь ВСЁ так*/
     Response.Write("<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"+base64String+"\" width=\"250\" height=\"400\" />");
    }
   }
  }
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  }
 }
}
```

**---2 вариант---**

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
   <img src="Handler1.ashx" />
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Handler1.ashx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication1 {
 public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler {

  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
   HttpRequest req = context.Request;
   HttpResponse response = context.Response;
   context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
   context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
   context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
   writeSingleImage(req.QueryString["Photo"], response.OutputStream);
  }

  private void writeSingleImage(string p, Stream stream) {
   //throw new NotImplementedException();
   byte[] img;
   string stringConnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["zzz"].ConnectionString;
   using(SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(stringConnect)) {
    connect.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT Photo FROM zzz";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connect);
    img = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   }
   stream.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
  }

  public bool IsReusable {
   get {
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В базе нужно не картинки хранить, а путь к ним. А картинки держать просто в файловой системе. В таком случае отображение картинки сведется к тривиальному считыванию пути, формированию ссылки и отправки ее в респонс.

Comment: Вообще-то это был не ответ: я размещал эту ремарку как комментарий под вопросом, не претендуя на ответ. Видимо, кому-то из модераторов пук моего мозга понравился и он его превратил из комментария в ответ.

Comment: Тогда прошу меня извинить

Answer (score 1):

```
/*вот здесь что-то не так...*/
```

Не так, потому что вы передаете не изображение, а массив байтов, с которым не понятно что должна программа делать. Должна быть как минимум еще строка

```
Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(byteArray));
```

И вот с этим pic вы уже можете работать как с рисунком.

Comment: 1. Base64 - это просто кодировка, если вы собираетесь передавать файл по сети в текстовом виде (но можно его, например, сохранить и передать ссылку). Просто в БД не хранятся "рисунки", или например "зипы", или прочие "файлы" - там хранятся массивы байтов.
2. Response.Write("<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"+base64String+"\" width=\"250\" height=\"400\" />")
Вот это вот довольно порочная практика, Вы сможете гарантировать что все файлы сейчас и все файлы в будущем будут 250*400px?
3. Разные форматы примеров наводят на мысль что вы их, не разобравшись, передрали из мсдн

Comment: Алгоритм следующий:
1. Читаем массив байтов
2. Преобразуем в конкретный файл
3. Читаем его свойства...
4. После чего уже можно осмысленно его передавать, сохранять, изменять...
5. ...
6. PROFIT

Comment: [Пример][1]


  [1]: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Интересно, почему Вы все здесь, а не в Силиконовой долине?

Answer (score 0):

я конечно дико извиняюсь, но зачем плодить лишние файлы в проекте если все это можно в одну строку записать?

```
<img src="data:image/*;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.cover, 0, item.cover.Length)" alt=@(item.title) width="100" height="100" />
```

где item - сущность вашей бд
cover - сам рисунок в байтах